# find count of distinct values in a column

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2012

Hi all am trying to build a sql query to display some information on a dashboard.

I have a table in which i store my sales data.My query needs to find total sales in last 7 days,average and group it based on region(which is present in user table.) .I created a temp table to get the item sales.DashBoard_Items table contains particular item that needs to be shown on dashboard.Now my problem is i need to get the store count of each region to find average sales.Can some one please help

```
Declare @TableTest 
table(itemid int,itemname varchar(100),itemdescription varchar(100),id int,itemidd int,userid int,orderdate varchar(40),qty int)

insert into @TableTest 
select * from DashBoard_Items join
 SalesQTY on SalesQTY.OrderDate>=  CONVERT(varchar(10) , DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE()),126) 
 and OOS_DashBoard_CoreItems.itemid=SalesQTY.itemid


select distinct t.userid,u.region from @TableTest t join users u on t.userid=u.userid and region is not null
```

above select query returns

[image]

how can i get region count from the above select query

```
    region             count
 5 - SUN WEST            2
 2 - LONG ISLAND         3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by `region` and then use `cont(*)`

```
SELECT region, count(*) 
FROM @TableTest
GROUP BY region;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    Region, 
    COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY Region
```

OR

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT Region, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Region)  AS [Count]
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.region, COUNT(*)
FROM @TableTest t JOIN users u ON t.userid=u.userid AND u.region IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY u.region
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
SELECT region, count( * )
FROM mytable
GROUP BY region
```